# What is the best way to store a common part of Strings in Java?

Tags: java, string, coding-style

I have some very similar string like this:

```
String first = "differentConfig1,config1,config2,config3,config4,config5,config6,config7,config8,config9";
String second = "differentConfig2,config1,config2,config3,config4,config5,config6,config7,config8,config9";
String third = "differentConfig3,config1,config2,config3,config4,config5,config6,config7,config8,config9";
```

where **config1 ... config9** are the same in each string, but **differentConfig1, differentConfig2 and differentConfig3** are different

what is the best way to avoid duplicating config1-9 in each string?

(Note that config1-9 are around 1 line long values)

What I have now is:

```
private String commonConfiguration() {
    return "config1,config2,config3,config4,config5,config6,config7,config8,config9"
}
```

and then the strings are constructed like this:

```
String first = "differentConfig1," + commonConfiguration();
```

I was thinking about using variables instead of a function, but I am afraid that a very long variable at the beginning of the function would make it less readable.

Comment: The "very long variable" will exist *somewhere*, does it really matter where? Although I might suggest using an array of strings and joining them; incrementally easier to read, modify, and reason about.

Comment: If it's a fixed string, a static final String is sufficient.

Comment: If you are worried about readability why not have a separate "config" class that has any static strings etc your project will need. Then you can just import when required

Comment: Wondering, how are these "configs" used later on? The code using this, does that *parse* your strings, and extract values and uses them for something? Meaning: conceptually, your configs could be an **enum**, and then different sets of configs are represented as EnumSet ... and only when you need to go "outside" of the JVM, you would have ONE piece of code that translates such EnumSets into strings. But passing around raw strings like ... as said: smells like a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration strings are better when stored in files. This is how most systems work too. Ex: Most systems like Kafka or Cassandra have configurations of loging, log file location, addresses etc in such configuration files.

So with this approach you can change these configuration strings as per a different environment as needed without impacting code.

With the use of a properties file, your input would just be a collection of key-value pairs.

firstConfig="differentConfig1,config1,config2,config3,config4,config5,config6,config7,config8,config9"
secondConfig="differentConfig2,config1,config2,config3,config4,config5,config6,config7,config8,config9"
thirdConfig="differentConfig3,config1,config2,config3,config4,config5,config6,config7,config8,config9"

I dont really suggest breaking it further, but if you are sure that they will always have the same commonPrefix, one option is to do something like this:

In your properties file,
firstConfig="differentConfig1"
secondConfig="differentConfig2"
thirdConfig="differentConfig3"
commonPrefix="config1,config2,config3....config9"

And in your code, you read these configuration string and append them. Something like this:

```
String c1 = Registry.getString("firstConfig")+Registry.getString("commonPrefix")
String c2 = Registry.getString("secondConfig")+Registry.getString("commonPrefix")
String c3 = Registry.getString("thirdConfig")+Registry.getString("commonPrefix")
```

Note: Properties file just a file that is present in your java project that holds the information of the configurations as a key-value pair.